# How to set initial condition to get the trajectory as a solution of the equation of the motion?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ode, odeint

I would like to see the solution of the equation of motion with the electrostatic force. What is wrong in the script below? It the problem in initial condition? Thank you

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def dr_dt(y, t):
    """Integration of the governing vector differential equation.
    d2r_dt2 = -(e**2/(4*pi*eps_0*me*r**2)) with d2r_dt2 and r as vecotrs.
    Initial position and velocity are given.
    y[0:2] = position components
    y[3:] = velocity components"""

    e = 1.602e-19 
    me = 9.1e-31
    eps_0 = 8.8541878128e-12
    r = np.sqrt(y[0]**2 + y[1]**2 + y[2]**2)

    dy0 = y[3]
    dy1 = y[4]
    dy2 = y[5]
    dy3 = -e**2/(4 * np.pi * eps_0 * me * (y[0])**2)
    dy4 = -e**2/(4 * np.pi * eps_0 * me * (y[1])**2)
    dy5 = -e**2/(4 * np.pi * eps_0 * me * (y[2])**2)
    return [dy0, dy1, dy2, dy3, dy4, dy5]

t = np.arange(0, 100000, 0.1)
y0 = [10, 0., 0., 0., 1.e3, 0.]
y = odeint(dr_dt, y0, t)
plt.plot(y[:,0], y[:,1])
plt.show()
```

This is the desired result of the shape of the trajectory:

[image]

I apply the following initial conditions:

```
t = np.arange(0, 2000, 0.1)   
y01 = [-200, 400., 0., 1., 0, 0.]                   
y02 = [-200, -400., 0., 1., 0, 0.]
```

and got this:

[image]

Why is the shape of the trajectory different?

Comment: There is something wrong with your equations.  The differential velocity shouldn't blow up if only a *component* is zero, maybe if *r* is zero it would make sense, but not a single component.  For example, say you're solving the problem for a fixed proton on the moon, and finding the motion for an electron on the earth. What should happen here is that dy3, dy4, dy5 are all very very small, but these questions say that it depends on your coordinate system, and if you happen to choose one where the electron is near the same axis as the proton dv is super large?

Comment: Check your sources again, something is wrong already in the differential equation. Take care to see the difference between the position vector `pos=y[:3]` and its length `r=sum(pos**2)**0.5`. If the equation relates to the potential `1/r`, then the force vector is proportional to `pos/r**3`.

Comment: I am solving the equation of motion for electric force (formula added to my question). What is wrong, please?

Comment: The formula is only for the size of the force, it does not contain the direction `\hat{r}=\vec{r}/r`. You need to be careful what is the scalar "radius" `r` and what is the position vector `\vec{r}` or `\mathbf{r}` or `\mathfrak{x}`, whatever the typographical convention is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The central force has indeed a magnitude of `F=-c/r^2`, `c=e**2/(4*pi*eps_0*me)` in radius direction. To get a vector valued force one needs to multiply this with the direction vector away from the center. This gives a vector force of `F=-c*x/r^3` where `r=|x|`.

```
def dr_dt(y, t):
    """Integration of the governing vector differential equation.
    d2x_dt2 = -(e**2*x/(4*pi*eps_0*me*r**3)) with d2x_dt2 and x as vectors, 
    r is the euclidean length of x.
    Initial position and velocity are given.
    y[:3] = position components
    y[3:] = velocity components"""

    e = 1.602e-19 
    me = 9.1e-31
    eps_0 = 8.8541878128e-12
    x, v = y[:3], y[3:]
    r = sum(x**2)**0.5
    a = -e**2*x/(4 * np.pi * eps_0 * me * r**3)
    return [*v, *a]

t = np.arange(0, 50, 0.1)
y0 = [-120, 40., 0., 4., 0., 0.]
y = odeint(dr_dt, y0, t)
plt.plot(y[:,0], y[:,1])
plt.show()
```

The initial conditions `[10, 0., 0., 0., 1.e3, 0.]` correspond to an electron that interacts with a proton fixed at the origin, starting 10m away and moving with 1000 m/s orthogonal to the radius direction. In the old physics (where you needed a proper filter for micron sized particles), this intuitively means that the electron flies away practically unhindered, after 1e5 s it will thus have a distance of 1e8 m, what the result of this code confirms.

---

As to the added picture of a hyperbolic swing-by, note that the conic section parametrization of the Kepler laws reads as

```
r(φ)= R/(1+E*cos(φ-φ_0))
```

which has its minimal radius `r=R/(1+E)` at `φ=φ_0`. The desired asymptotes are at about `φ=π` and `φ=-π/4` moving clockwise. This then gives `φ_0=3π/8` as the angle of the symmetry axis and `E=-1/cos(π-φ_0)=1/cos(φ_0)` as excentricity. To incorporate the height of the horizontal asymptote into the calculation, compute the `y` coordinate as

```
y(φ) = R/E * sin(φ)/(cos(φ-φ_0)+cos(φ0))
     = R/E * sin(φ/2)/cos(φ/2-φ_0)

in the limit

y(π)=R/(E*sin(φ_0))
```

As the graphic sets `y(π)=b`, we get `R=E*sin(φ_0)*b`.

The velocity far away from the origin is `r'(-oo)=sqrt(E^2-1)*c/K`, where `K` is the constant or the area law `r(t)^2*φ'(t)=K`, with `K^2=R*c`. Take that as the approximate initial velocity in horizontal direction at the initial point `[ x0,y0] = [-3*b,b]`.

So with `b = 200` this results in the initial condition vector

```
y0 = [-600.0, 200.0, 0.0, 1.749183465630342, 0.0, 0.0]
```

and integrating to `T=4*b` gives the plot

[image: hyperbolic orbit]

The initial condition in the code above is for `b=40` which results in a similar image.

More shots using `b=200`, multiplying the initial velocity with `0.4,0.5,...,1.0,1.1`

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. Initial condition seems to be the problem. You are dividing by zero in `dy4` and `dy5`, which is causing the `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered`.

Replacing the starting condition with this:

```
y0 = [10, 20., 20., 1., 1.e3, 0]
```

Gives the following output:[image]